# Help with 'Terminator' config, or any tool that can do the same functionality

Tags: terminator

During developing a project I had to open multiple tabs in gnome-terminal, some of them as just output streams, others for the shell prompt.

Is their a way to automate this task.
Like running a script that automatically opens multiple terminals and run certain commands on each of them, and these terminals are displayed vertically or horizontally rather than in tabs ( or different windows ) like grid-display or something.

'Terminator' does exactly what I want, but I just can't configure it to work like what I want.
I don't get the 'Layout' thing

Here's part of my 'config' file:

```
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child1]]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      position = left
   [[[child2]]]
      type = Terminal
      parent = window0
      position = left
   [[[window0]]]
      type = Window
      parent = ""
```

When I run terminator, an error is printed out saying that I there's an incorrect number of children, and then 'terminator' appears normally with a single terminal.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, I would appreciate any help with 'Terminator' or with any tool that has the same functionality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to try [terminator](https://github.com/achiu/terminitor) a ruby gem that will help you to mange automation config files.

> Terminitor automates your development workflow setup. Less time setting up, more time getting things done.

Also, an alternative is [teamocil](https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil)

> Teamocil is a tool used to automatically create windows and splits in tmux with Ruby and YAML. Like tmuxinator, but with splits, not just windows.

Comment: see http://thechangelog.com/post/3164295957/teamocil-ruby-yaml-tmux-layouts and http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/terminitor-hasta-la-vista-redundant-commands/

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using 'screen' ? there is a 'split' command.

- "CTRL+a, S" (Capital S) to create a new tab
- "CTRL+a, Tab" to Switch to this tab
- "CTRL+a, c" to create a new screen in this tab

Comment: As far as I know, screen doesn't expose any decent way to use these key-binding to automate the procedure with a script. So, Unfortunately, I can't use it in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suggest you to forget terminator (coming from a looong time terminator user) and learn to use a terminal multiplexer like tmux. There's a gem called [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) that lets you configure sessions with YAML, so it's really, really easy.

For tmux I suggest you to start with the book «[tmux: Productive Mouse-Free Development](http://pragprog.com/book/bhtmux/tmux)» from Brian Hoogan.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on  a shell script to do exactly what you need

https://github.com/vahidhedayati/terminator-win-splitter

chmod to 755

./termcon.sh  -h

./termcon.sh  -c  {connects to existing layouts - press enter and it will list your existing layouts }

./termcon.sh  -f filename.txt  {connects to servers listing within filename.txt  and stores layout }

./termcon.sh  -l prod ta ce cex {LISTS auto discovered nodes for ce cex in production env  which have tomcat or apache in naming } }

./termcon.sh  -a prod ta ce cex {Connects to auto discovered nodes for ce cex in production env which have tomcat or apache in naming  and stores layout}

I am still working on windows split, it is quite complex but for now it does a 4 window split with no issues, when it is working and i emailed again it will just be a case of

./termcon.sh  -w 8 -a prod ta ce cex

./termcon.sh  -w 8 -f file.txt

I would also recommend if calling via a file then to name files according to server naming convention since once a layout is stored it won't overwrite it