# View more terminal (terminator) history while in session

Tags: terminal, octave, terminator

I've made a stupid mistake and run an Octave session overnight to produce results to the terminal, with the intention of manually copying and pasting the terminal output to a file. However, I now find that I can't scroll far enough back to copy all the session output. What can I do to access the current session history that is not observable in the terminal window? An added complication is that the terminal I'm using is terminator and there doesn't seem to be an edit option, so edit -> select all -> copy is not available to me. As I write this, the terminal and Octave session are still open, and I need to view the earlier history *without* either quitting Octave or closing the terminal.

Comment: The history has a finite size, once you wrote more than it can fit then the first commands are lost forever. If you want to record your input you should use the function 'diary', check the help.

Answer (score 0):

suggest u look at [my  other post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346765/help-with-terminator-config-or-any-tool-that-can-do-the-same-functionality)

this tool lets u auto connect but as part of the global configuration it sets history as unlimited.

Once you run it for the first time your config file is generated and puts these in

```
     cat  ~/.config/terminator/config|head -15
[global_config]
  enabled_plugins = LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
  title_transmit_bg_color = "#ef191d"
[keybindings]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    scrollback_infinite = True
    split_to_group = True
    foreground_color = "#ffffff"
[layouts]
```

as you can see the default config as scrll back inifinite true